# Can not print to file using IO Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

Hello i have done my JSon type and i am trying to it to a file.
I can do this from the prelude but i can't do it when using the IO Monad.I get the following `error`:

```
 Main.hs:13:24: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Char
    * In the second argument of `writeFile', namely `val'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: writeFile out val
      In the expression:
        do val <- renderJValue sample
           writeFile out val
   |
13 |          writeFile out val
   |                        ^^^
```

**Main**

```
 module Main where
        import Jlib
        import Put
        import Data.Typeable

        import System.Environment

        out="data.txt"

        main::IO()
        main=do
             val<-renderJValue sample
             writeFile out val
```

Why would this not work in the IO Monad since `renderJValue sample` in the prelude works ok .

**Jlib.hs**

```
data JValue=JString String
                |JNumber Double
                |JBool Bool
                |JNull
                |JObject [(String,JValue)]
                |JArray [JValue]
                deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

**Put.hs**

```
sample=JArray[
                    JObject [("name",JString "adita"),("age",JNumber 13)],
                    JObject [("name",JString "dan"),("kids",JNumber 3)] ,
                    JNumber 3,
                    JBool False,
                    JString "Howdy"
                    ]
```

**P.S** `renderJValue` returns a string

**P.S:** if i start the prelude i load the module and i render the value it works:

```
Prelude System.Environment Put> :load Put
Ok, two modules loaded.
Prelude System.Environment Put> renderJValue sample
"[{name:adita,age:13.0},{name:dan,kids:3.0},3.0,False,Howdy]"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You here use `renderJValue sample` as if it is an `IO String`:

```
main :: IO()
main=do
     val <- renderJValue sample
     writeFile out val
```

But it is in fact (given it is a function similar to [this one](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html)) a function with signature `renderJValue :: JValue -> String`. So no `IO` is involved. In that case we do not use the arrow notation.

We can call the function "*inline*":

```
main :: IO()
main = do
     writeFile out (renderJValue sample)
```

or even shorter:

```
main :: IO()
main = writeFile out (renderJValue sample)
```

But in case the expression is rather long, this can become quite ugly. We can decide to use a `let` statement in that case.

You can solve this by either removing the `putStrLn`:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    let val = renderJValue sample
    writeFile out val
```

Comment: Hey.I am sorry that was a typo.I updated the original post with further information.

Comment: Then the proposed solution is still valid: you need to use a `let` statement here, and not a `<-`, since `renderJValue` is (as far as I know) not monadic?

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?When to use `<-` vs `let` regarding monads?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: well the result of monadic actions are catched with `<-` for the others, you can decide to inline it (i.e. `writeFile out (renderJValue sample)`, but this leads to complicated code), or by using `let` statements, that act like a `let ... in ...` in non-`do` blocks.

Comment: I thought that inside the  Monad you can not use `=` only `<-`.Outside monad i have used `let` and  `where` clauses etc..i know these constructs but do not know how they are used in `IO`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: well `do` notation is actually only syntactical sugar. If you write `do {x <- f; g x}`, you have actually written `f >>= g`. And like in non-do blocks, you can use a `let` clause.

Comment: Use `foo <- bar` whenever `bar` returns an *action* in the current monad (e.g., `IO Integer`). Use `let foo = bar` whenever `bar` does *not* return an action in the current monad (e.g., `Integer`).

Comment: Oh so to use `<- method` ,`method` has to have some side effects like doing some IO stuff on its own? So `method` should be `method::IO Something` where something is a type.In my case i could create a wrapper for `putStrLn ` that has a `do `inside it  and it would work.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: more or less, although `do` works with other monadic types than `IO` like `Maybe` and `[]`, etc. (which makes it quite hard to understand at first). But you can say that it has to be an `IO Something`, whether it really has side effects is of no importance.